# Remove Square Brackets and Line Breaks in String with regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to remove a section of a string with square brackets and numbers `"[11257]"` from a longer string `"[11257] 39558 39566 39569 39570 39572 39576 39577"`. This is fairly simple to do.

```
easy_string <- "[11257] 39558 39566 39569 39570 39572 39576 39577"
sub("\\[.*?\\]", "\\1", easy_string, perl = TRUE)
```

Which returns what I expect:

```
[1] " 39558 39566 39569 39570 39572 39576 39577"
```

However, I cannot figure out how to adapt my regex pattern to select multiple occurrences. Plus, the more difficult string includes linebreaks, as in:

```
hard_string <- "[11257] 39558 39566 39569 39570 39572 39576 39577 39583
[11269] 39592 39595 39596 39597 39600 39602 39607 39608 39611 39616 39618
[11281] 39621 39623 39624 39627 39631 39632 39633 39635 39639 39641 39644 
[11293] 39649 39650 39656 39658 39667 39670 39671 39681 39682 39683 39684 
[11305] 39694 39695 39704 39711 39712 39714 39715 39723"
```

When I run my `sub()` command, R returns:

```
[1] " 39558 39566 39569 39570 39572 39576 39577 39583\n[11269] 39592 39595 
39596 39597 39600 39602 39607 39608 39611 39616 39618\n[11281] 39621 39623 
39624 39627 39631 39632 39633 39635 39639 39641 39644 \n[11293] 39649 39650 
39656 39658 39667 39670 39671 39681 39682 39683 39684 \n[11305] 39694 39695 
39704 39711 39712 39714 39715 39723"
```

How can I remove all of the square brackets, and the numbers inside them, when a string includes linebreaks?

**ANSWER**

Thanks to akrun, I used `gsub()` and saved the result so I could remove the linebreaks in a second `gsub()` call.

```
hard_fixed <- gsub("\\[.*?\\]\\s", "\\1", hard_string, perl = TRUE)
gsub("\\\n", "\\1", hard_fixed, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `gsub` (global substitution) instead `sub` for removing multiple occurrences of the pattern.  The `sub` will only match with the first occurrence of the pattern

```
gsub("\\[.*?\\]\\s", "\\1", hard_string, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Then, to remove the linebreaks, I used: `hard_fixed <- gsub("\\[.*?\\]\\s", "\\1", hard_string, perl = TRUE)`
`gsub("\\\n", "\\1", hard_fixed, perl = TRUE)`